# Calculate a position based on an angle a speed and a starting position

Tags: delphi, math, angle

Althougth i have read many articles on internet regarding it, i m unable to solve my issue.

There is a 2D plan where x, y is the top left point of the screen.
I have a point from which i know the position x, y, the direction (0 to 360 degrees) and a speed (in pixel per step ).

According to what i have read, if i want to calculate the next position of the point after one step i use the following code:

```
  self.px.X := round(self.px.X + self.speed * cos(direction));
  self.px.Y := round(self.px.Y + Self.speed * sin(direction));
```

For testing purpose i use a speed value of 10 and a direction of 90.
Normally, the point should move horizontally (or even vertically would be a progress), but it is moving in a diagonal movement, not even something like 45°.

Anyone knows what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: The argument of Sin and Cos must be in radians, as is fairly clearly stated in [the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Sin). 90 degrees = Pi/2 radians. Also, you must multiply your velocity with the time difference between each step.

Comment: You should use floating point numbers for the (x, y) coordinates and the speed and convert to Integer only for display purposes. The consecutive application of Round can result in substantial rounding errors. For a speed below 0.5 your x, y coordinates will not move at all.

Comment: @SergedeGossondeVarennes, i can't find any reference to the distcos and distsin function in delphi.

Comment: @Andreas, you were right, i used the DegToRad functions and the movement looks like following the right angle. You are also right for the time, i know it, for now i focus on things i don't understand, later on i will apply a time based formula and use floating points as recommended by Matej as well. thanks to you.

Comment: @fpiette for som reason I could not access my comment. Deleted it instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by Andreas Rejbrand (but i don't know how to turn a comment into an answer, sorry Andreas), the solution was to use radians number by simply calling degToRad function:

```
self.px.X := round(self.px.X + self.speed * cos(DegToRad(direction)));
self.px.Y := round(self.px.Y + Self.speed * sin(DegToRad(direction)));
```

Comment: It is perfectly ok to write an answer based on a comment by somebody else. It can be thought that the person who commented didn't feel they have the time or will or whatever to write a proper answer. You can also mark your own answer as the correct one (by clicking the tick mark beside your answer green). Though, you will not be rewarded the reps for a correct answer, on an answer to your own question. Marking an answer as correct hints future readers, that the problem has a solution.